# How to use 2 Services exported from an abstract class in angular 4.3

Tags: angular, typescript, abstract-class

i want to use 2 Services, which get their method from an abstract class, in the same component.
By defining one Service in the component its working, but i don't know how to provide a second Service in my component.

This is my **abstract-class**-Service:

```
@Injectable()
export abstract class AbstractclassService {
public onMessage(msg: string): void {
    console.log("Testing");
  }
}
```

In my **test-component** i want to use two Services (Testservice1 and Testservice2)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  providers: [
    {
      provide: AbstractclassService,
      useFactory: Testservice1
    }

    ],
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})
export class TestComponent implements  OnInit{

  data = [
    {
      name: 'test',
      value: ''
    }
  ];
constructor( private abstractclassService: AbstractclassService) {

  }

ngOnInit () {

    this.abstractclassService.onMessage = (msg: string) => {
      this.data = [{name: 'test', value: msg}];
  };


}
```

This is my **Testservice1**, Testservice2 has the same structur:

```
@Injectable()
export class TestService1 extends AbstractclassService   {

public constructor(private http: Http) {
    super();
.
.  METHOD1
.

this.onMessage(result);
          };
```

The code is working with one Service, Testservice1 or Testservice2, but i didn't get it how to use both at the same time.

Comment: Did you ever fix it?

Comment: No...I think that isnt possible this way!